# How to handle < and > symbols in HttpService if we use xml as a result format?

Tags: xml, tags, httpservice

I used a httpservice which returns a xml as a result.But the content itself has a '<' symbol or '>' symbol , it leads to error ! How can i handle this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either escape the content or enclose it in cdata.
see http://xml.silmaril.ie/authors/specials/

Comment: RC,
Thanks for your reply.
Im analysing the part.
Will post the details once it is done.